# Storing a 1D array of strings in Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android

I have two arrays, the first consists of 9 buttons. The second can hold 9 Strings. I have a method called getPlayerChoiceText to populate the String array with the text that is set on each button from the `playerchoice` Array. How can I save this text using SharedPreferences?

```
private String[] getPlayerChoiceText()
{
    playerchoiceText[0] = playerchoice[0].getText().toString();
    playerchoiceText[1] = playerchoice[1].getText().toString();
    playerchoiceText[2] = playerchoice[2].getText().toString();
    playerchoiceText[3] = playerchoice[3].getText().toString();
    playerchoiceText[4] = playerchoice[4].getText().toString();
    playerchoiceText[5] = playerchoice[5].getText().toString();
    playerchoiceText[6] = playerchoice[6].getText().toString();
    playerchoiceText[7] = playerchoice[7].getText().toString();
    playerchoiceText[8] = playerchoice[8].getText().toString();

    return playerchoiceText;
}

   private void saveData()
   {
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
      playerchoiceText = getPlayerChoiceText();
   }
```

Comment: Why do you maintain two arrays for this? Can't you use a `Map<Button, String>`? I think `SharedPreferences` are storing key-value pairs, which would go very well with a `Map`.

Comment: If it has to be `SharedPreferences`, concatenate your array of string into one long `String` and use delimiters between them (for example `:`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the same problem. I solved it by using `JSONArray`.

```
JSONArray choices = new JSONArray();
choices.put("1");
choices.put("2");
choices.put("3");

// Save
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("choices", choices.toString());

// Retrieve
choices = new JSONArray(sharedPreferences.getString("choices", "[]"));
```

In this way, you can easily do `Insert` and `Delete` operations. I hope this helps.

Comment: Good suggestion +1.  I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Android's `SharedPreferences` operates as a key value store, and does not allow you to directly store Java objects.  So, representing your player choice text values as a map would make more sense, if you want to store them using shared preferences.

There is one trick you might be able to use here, if you wanted to continue representing your choice texts as an array.  You could store the texts using a delimiter, e.g. pipe:

```
String choices = String.join("|", playerchoiceText);
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString("choices", choices).apply();
```

And then, on the way out:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String[] playerchoiceText = prefs.getString("choices", "").split("\\|");
```

Comment: Would this be done better if i used a List? Instead of a regular 1d array?

Comment: The issue still remains the same, namely that shared prefs using a map functionality to store its data.  So, you would need to adapt to a map interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use `put/getStringSet()`:

```
private void saveData()
   {
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
      String[] playerchoiceText = getPlayerChoiceText();
      editor.putStringSet("player_choice", new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(playerchoiceText)); 
      editor.commit();
   }
```