# Storing ArrayList<Double> in SharedPreferences or Sqlite

Tags: android, arrays, list, preferences, shared

Im  storing users location in Arraylist now I want after the click on finish button to store the two ArrayList lat ,ArrayLis lng into SharedPreferences the later to display the data .

Is it possible to do this with Sharedpreferences or is it better to use Sqlite ?

Thanks !

Comment: you can (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876680/is-it-possible-to-add-an-array-or-object-to-sharedpreferences-on-android), but I would personally avoid storing big arrays and polluting the shared preferences. Also if it's important information the shared preferences get erased if the user clears the cache/data of the app, so keep that in mind

Comment: Do you want to persist data ? or Do you want to share data between activities ?

Comment: Basically I want persist data ,having one MapsActivity and after the array list is saved user will choose wich array list he wants to be displayed and then I want to display the array list in another MapsActivity .

Comment: You can check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53325509/1496502. It is applicable for any 1D arrays with different datatypes.

Comment: Uma Sankar - if I convert double to String how can I later retrieve and convert string to double again ?